# INSERT INTO linked server on Trigger OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server does not support the required transaction interface

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-server-express

I have created a stored procedure, which among other things contains and INSERT into an Access linked server. I want to trigger this stored procedure upon INSERT into an SQL table.

If I run the stored procedure manually, it works great, but if I try to EXEC from a trigger I get:

```
The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "AccessDB" does not support the required transaction interface.
```

I have tried both with OPENQUERY

```
INSERT OPENQUERY ([AccessDB], 'SELECT Teilenummer FROM Teilenummern')
VALUES (@cntDSN)
```

and without

```
INSERT INTO [AccessDB]...Teilenummern
SELECT 'TEST1234'
```

But I get the same result. If I open a new query in SSMS, and run EXEC [dbo].[SQL_ACCESS_SYNC] it works fine, but calling the same within a trigger on the table, it fails. What am I missing

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, anything that happens in a trigger happens in the transaction which causes the trigger to fire, so you want a transaction that both modifies SQL server and MS Access at the same time. I don't think that can be done. Generally, working with linked servers and different RBMSes in triggers is not a good plan. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have an external device that writes some 12 values to the SQL table. I then need to copy 6 of those values to an Access table when a new entry occurs in the SQL.